# PHP convert string to html and parse the html file

Tags: php, html

I would like to parse an HTML file in order to extract some information.

My code is:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/myFiles/';
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($response);
if (!empty($html)) {
    foreach($html->find('tr td a') as $a) {
        echo $a->href.", ";
    }
}
```

As I can see, $response is a string and not an html file.  That's why I get error message: `Call to a member function find() on a non-object`.

Comment: Try using `json_decode($response, true);` It should create a json array of your string.

Comment: "It's a string" – Well yes, HTML is a string. What does that string contain?!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to load `html`s instead of contents as follows

```
   $url = 'http://localhost/myFiles/';

   $html = file_get_html($url);
   foreach($html->find('tr td a') as $a) {
      echo $a->href.", ";
    }
```